# [edited]Prove that $f(x)=0$ exists in a certain interval.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I have $f:R \rightarrow R$, $f(0)=-1$ and $f'(x) \ge1$ $\forall x$. I need to show that $f(x)=0$, for some $x\in[0,1]$
I know that I need to use mean value theorem and intermediate value theorem.

## Corrected question

I got $f(1)\ge0$ by mean value theorem.
It seems it is proved since $f(1)=0$ and this was what I needed. $x=1$
But I know I am supposed to use intermediate value theorem too. I don't know where and how I need intermediate value theorem.

## Original question which was somewhat wrong

So I got $f(1)\ge2$ by mean value theorem.
Then by intermediate value theorem I can show that $f(x)=0$ exists on $(0,1)$.
This is enough since I know $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are not $0$.
So even if I was asked to show on the closed interval, I actually can show on the open interval where I know the value of the end points.
I think I got it right but I usually got at least a tiny thing wrong.
Can someone see if I am right and suggest to improve rigorousness of my proof?

Comment: You should have gotten $f(1) \geq 0$ using mean value theorem.

Comment: What do you mean $f(1)\geq 2$?? What if $f(x)=x-1$? You can actually obtain $f(1)\geq 0$, but that's it... Anyway, IF you knew that $f(1)$ was not $0$, your argument would be correct ($f(1)$ can be zero, see $f(x)=x-1$).

Comment: Yea, $f(1)\ge0$ I was stupid. Then my argument below that line doesn't make sense. I think I need more help than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is no $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Then $f(1) < 0$, as $f(1) \neq 0$ by hypothesis and if $f(1)$ were positive then there would be such an $x$ by the IVP.

However by the MVT there is a $c \in (0,1)$ such that

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} = f(1) + 1 < 1$$

This contradicts the hypothesis that $f'(x) \geq 1$ for all $x$. Therefore there must be an $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Can you explain why I am wrong if I only use MVT?

Comment: Perhaps there is such a proof. We can only tell if you write out your entire proof in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)\geq 0$ by the MVT. Now $f(0)f(1)<0$ so by Bolzano's theorem;

$$f(0)f(1)<0\implies \exists_!\, x_0\in (0,1) \colon f(x_0)=0$$

Comment: Sorry for confusion. $f(1)\ge0$ not $2$. Also I only want to use MVT and IVT.

Comment: It works for $f(1)\geq 0$ too. Bolzano's theorem is a special case of IVT.

Comment: Ok. I didn't learn Bolazano's yet but I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kane actually you did, you just didn't name it.